# Migrating MVC to MVVM in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, mvvm

Working sample available at: https://gitlab.com/nipunrd_git/mvvmarch

I am in process of migrating an app from MVC to MVVM. As far as I have read, you need to make your `viewController` independent of the `Model`, there by making a `viewModel` to glue the model and the controller together.

If we consider a simple `screenA` which has a refresh button to get some data via a web service and then fill the data in the view:

1. `ScreenAViewController.swift`: Will contain the code to hit the web service via a singleton network helper class.

   `ScreenA -> NetworkHandler -> fetchData`
2. In order to make ScreenA, use the fetched data, we should now make a `ViewModel`, so I made `ScreenAViewModel`. Let's say our model was named "Design":

`struct Design{
     var pattern: String
    }`

Now our ViewModel would look like this:

```
class ScreenAViewModel{
 private let design: Design
 public let pattern: String

init (design: Design, pattern: String){
   self.design = design
   self.pattern = design.pattern
  }
}
```

3. When we get the data from the web service, we should first create a `Design` model and then initialize our ViewModel with that. This ViewModel will now be used by our view controller to fetch and display data from. Any Business logic will be written in this only.

Is there a way to shift #3 to the view model itself? I think by having this conversion from model to viewModel in the controller itself is beating the purpose of hiding model from controller.

Comment: Your view model should get passed into the controller. That way it is truly independent of the controller. Whoever creates the controller should have the view model ready to pass in. Also you have an extra parameter on the initializer for the view model.

Comment: What if it is the first view of my app? Shall I then call the API in the Appdelegate then ? AppDelegate -> Network Handler -> fetchData -> Initialize ViewModel -> Call ViewController with the ViewModel?

Comment: The API calls should be in the view model. So move the Network Handler -> fetchData into the view model.

Comment: There are ways to pass in 'providers' / 'services' into the view model. This basically abstracts the network handling code away from the view model. In that case the code still gets called in the view model but it looks a lot simpler and you can create mock data providers and test the view model via unit tests.

Comment: I understand your point. But imagine a case of an app screen, which only has a "GetStarted" button. So when we present this screen, there is no data at play and hence no ViewModel till now. Now when you tap "Get Started", the same screen fetches 3 options from a web service and displays them underneath "GetStarted". So we are on same screen/controller and where do we inject the `ViewModel` now on the same screen?

Comment: That screen should be backed by a view model from the start. The view model should have a `func getStarted()` that gets called when the user taps 'Get Started'. That function in the view model will get the appropriate data and alert the controller that it has new data. Then the controller can get the data off the view model and display it. Thus the view model is there from the start. Even if it has no data to begin with.

Comment: I have just made a minor sample for this on github, please check if it has the flow for what you explained: https://gitlab.com/nipunrd_git/mvvmarch

Comment: Looks nice. If you want to raise a flag when the view model is unexpectedly `nil` you can explicitly unwrap the view model property. For the `ProfileServices`, if you want to mock them, you create a protocol that has the `fetchProfileData` function and you modify the initializer of the view model to take in that protocol. You probably don't need the singleton pattern for `ProfileServices`. You can then pass an instance of the protocol-conforming `ProfileServices` to the view model.

Comment: Added a protocol-conforming ProfileServices to the view model. So now I guess, my view model is taking care of Model, Network Hooks and allowing my view to only see public mappings of my original model. Please check once if possible and suggest any further improvement.